# Match value from other field same row

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hello,

I've got a table like

| Zone | Category |
| --- | --- |
| Europe | Global |
| Asia | Global |
| Ameriaca | Global |
| Local Grocery | Local |
| Local Automotive | Local |
| Local HR | Local |

and I want to create a calculated column to look like

| Zone | Category | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Europe | Global | Europe |
| Asia | Global | Asia |
| America | Global | America |
| Local Grocery | Local | Local |
| Local Automotive | Local | Local |
| Local HR | Local | Local |

Comment: did you try anything by yourself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must try yourself how to manage such simple codes...

```
Result =
IF ( 'Table (2)'[Category] = "Local", "Local", 'Table (2)'[Zone ] )
```

Comment: I promise I did that myself and It didn't work so I went to stackoverflow.. thanks